# How to get the value that is returned from the kendoui upload success or complete function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI upload control. I have defined the Kendo UI upload like this:

```
<input type="file" name="resume" />
$("#file").kendoUpload({
    async: {
         saveUrl: "/Home/SaveResume",             
         autoUpload: true
         },            
         complete: function (e)
         {
            // here i want to get the text that is returned from the controller
         }
});
```

The controller code is like:

```
public ActionResult SaveResume(HttpPostedFileBase resume)
{
    var text;
    // code for the file to convert to text and assign it to text
    return Json(text, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

After returning the code I want to retrieve the code in complete function. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(e)` to see what's returned? i'm willing to be `e` is not an `event` but is rather the `data returned from the srever`. If you use `var data = $.parseJSON(e)` you probably end up with a data object that has properties as defined by your controller.

Comment: Yah the data variable contains the string like `Server Response: the actual string`.

Comment: The item being returned `is` an object, you used parseJSON and it wasn't the object you send? post the object here, use jsfiddle and save it.

Comment: After parsing i am getting the data like Server Resonse: the data. How can i take the actual string now.

Comment: This Kendo UI help topic describes how to retrieve data from the save handler: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/upload/metadata#receiving-metadata-from-the-save-handler

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the response to success function like this

```
function onSuccess(e)
{
    var response = e.response.data();
}
```

where the return json could be

```
return Json(new { data = text }, "text/plain");
```

Comment: please see nukefusion's answer. `e.response.data()` doesn't work.

Comment: The Content-Type of the response should be `text/plain` to return data to the event handler, including returning a JSON object. Any other content type will be treated as an error.
`e.response.data()` should be `e.response.data`, since the response is expected to be an object.
To return that object containing a `data` property from the controller, the code should be `return Json(new { data = text }, "text/plain");`.

Answer (score 10):

If you just passing a string back you should be able to do:

```
function onSuccess(e) {
    var text = e.XMLHttpRequest.responseText;
}
```

You could also pass back a more complex object, if required:

```
// Object
public class MyObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

// Controller Action
public virtual ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    return this.Json(new MyObject(), "text/plain");
}

// Javascript Handler
function onSuccess(e) {
    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(e.XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    var id = response.ID;
    var text = response.Text;
}
```

Comment: We need to return only text/plain. can we send other formats like html or xhtml

Answer (score 1):

I'll add my answer alongside the other valid answers here.  First though you will want to get the returned response in the success function instead of the complete function:

```
        $("#files").kendoUpload({
        async: {
            saveUrl: url,
            removeUrl: removeUrl,
            autoUpload: true
        },
        select: onFileSelect,       // function for when a file is selected
        success: onFileSuccess,     // function that returns response after upload
        complete: onFileComplete,   // function after success
        remove: onFileRemove,       // function for when a file is removed
        });
```

The on success function returns an object (normally people name it e)

```
function onFileSuccess(e) {

    console.log("e.response", e.response);
    console.log("e.operation", e.operation);
    console.log("e.XMLHttpRequest.status", e.XMLHttpRequest.status);

    //e.operation is upload or remove
    if (e.operation === "upload") {
        // a file was added, get the response
        var fileid = e.response;
    } else {
        // Do something after a file was removed
    }
}
```

My console.log entries return this data:

[console.log values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxuvc.png)

This is how I return my data from the server:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage InsertTempFile()
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

        //........
        // Code that adds my file to the database
        // and generates a new primary key for my file
        //.........

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(myNewId.ToString());

        return response;
    }
```

The response.Content returns my new Id in e.response
The HttpStatusCode.Ok returns my status of 200.  There's a bunch of other data that is returned as well if you inspect the response.

Note that to use HttpResponseMessage and HttpStatuseCode you need to include the following namespaces in your class:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
```